# Why does jQuery always return 'open' for $.attr('open'), regardless of the actual value of the attribute?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-attributes

In jQuery, why does this:

```
$('<div open="whatever">').attr('open')
```

Always evaluate to `'open'` instead of `'whatever'`? In contrast, this:

```
$('<div asdf="whatever">').attr('asdf')
```

Evaluates to `'whatever'` as expected.

Yes, I am aware that `open` and `asdf` are not valid HTML attributes; I'm not looking for answers that say something along the lines of "just use `data-open`", etc... I am looking for an explanation of the above behavior.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place?  It's probably undocumented behavior.

Comment: @helixed haven't you ever just been curious? ;-) Ben may have been using the arbitrary attribute (modern browsers will support this) and when his application didn't work, he eventually noticed it was the `open` attribute and wondered "huh? why?"

Comment: @helixed, I noticed when working with some html for legacy code base that used the bare `open=` attribute. So the answer is "I wouldn't be trying to do this in the first place, I'd use a data- attribute".

Comment: @Ben Lee I wasn't trying to criticize you for asking.  I was just wondering under what circumstances you would want to know this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open` is actually a [valid attribute for HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_details_open.asp) that's meant to be a boolean. If that's the case, I suspect that if you have "open" set at all, the browser is evaluating it as true and returning that it is "open".

I'd be more curious to know why it's returning "open" instead of "true". Probably due to incomplete implementation in various browsers. In one way or another they may have set that attribute aside for later.

[addendum: as per comments, this seems to be the way HTML treats booleans]

Comment: Isn't that how HTML treats booleans? `checked="checked"`, etc?

Comment: Could be! I actually haven't thought about it that way. In which case it's behaving the way it should.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea "open" was a valid attribute! I'm having trouble finding it in the html5 specs though, do you by chance have a link? (If not, that's fine)

Comment: Well, I'm embarrased to say it because I know the scorn it gets around here, but I stumbled across it here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_details_open.asp -- and if I'm understanding correctly it's only supposed to be valid for a "details" tag. But incomplete or incorrect implementations being what they are... ;-)

Comment: Aha: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element

Comment: But yeah, just the "details" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Did some testing, and for some reason this seems to work:

```
document.getElementById('myID').getAttribute('open');
```

While jQuery does not work for neither .prop() or .attr()

Strange indeed?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/72yNK/)